# How to put my function into a thread Qt Concurrent

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread, qtconcurrent

I have function like this

```
QList<MyObject*> list;

for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
{
    auto *object = new MyObject(this);
    ProcessFunc1(object);
    ProcessFunc2(object);
    
    ProcessFunc3(object); // a heavy function that I would like to parallelize

    list.push_back(object);
}

return list;
```

I need to correctly parallelize this function. What is the best way to do it?

I wrote it like this, but I'm not sure it's correct:

```
QList<MyObject*> list;
QFutureSynchronizer<MyObject*> syncronizer;
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
{
    auto future = QtConcurrent::run([this]() -> MyObject* {
        auto *object = new MyObject(this);
        ProcessFunc1(object);
        ProcessFunc2(object);
    
        ProcessFunc3(object); // a heavy function that I would like to parallelize
        return object;
});
    syncronizer.addFuture(future);
}

syncronizer.waitForFinished();

for (int i = 0; i < syncronizer.futures().count(); ++i)
    list.push_back(syncronizer.futures().at(i).result());

return list;
```

Comment: You need to clarify your exact goal. Do you want to parellize to increase performance? Or just so that the UI is not blocked? If you want to increase performance, then maybe use blockingMapped and let Qt handle the rest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// create the objects in the main thread:
// creating objects in another thread can result in pain,
// see e.g. https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qobject.html#thread-affinity
QList<MyObject *> list;
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    list.emplaceBack(this); // equivalent to list.append(new MyObject(this))
// "map" (== "apply") your function to all objects in parallel, wait for the result
QtConcurrent::blockingMap(list, [] {
    ProcessFunc1(object);
    ProcessFunc2(object);
    ProcessFunc3(object);
});
// here everything is done, since blockingMap waits for everything to finish
```